# Obtaining text from nested spans with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a hard time working with jquery to obtain the text value of in a nested span. Lets say I have the following structure:

```
<span class='token tag'>
    <span class='token tag'>
        <span class='token punctuation'> < </span>
            div
        </span>
    ...
```

My goal is to obtain the text div. This pattern holds for all names of opening tags and I would like to select to select all elements with matching names (all divs) following this pattern. I have the following:

```
$(this.state.$html.filter('.token.tag:has(> .token.tag):has(> .token.punctuation).children()[3]).text()
```

This was my best attempt so far but its unsuccessful.

Comment: please clarify the html structure it is not clear

Comment: according to the code above, there seems to have a html typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want the text inside nested span, it is better to apply the search with span tag, so that it will eliminate other elements like div.

So if you have a nested div with same classes, it will not be selected.

```js
var txt = $("span.token.tag > span.token.tag > span.token.punctuation").text()
console.log(txt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class='token tag'>
  <span class='token tag'>
    <span class='token punctuation'>div</span>
  </span>
</span>

<div class='token tag'>
  <div class='token tag'>
    <div class='token punctuation'>div2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div  = $('.token').find('span.tag').children('span').text();
console.log(div)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='token tag'>
    <span class='token tag'>
        <span class='token punctuation'>div</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

try this one.